# Выражение "в противность чему-то"

Tags: лексика, устаревшие-слова

С удивлением увидел, что в писатели прошлого, позапрошлого века часто употребляли это выражение ([примеры из Нацкорпуса](http://search2.ruscorpora.ru/search.xml?env=alpha&mycorp=&mysent=&mysize=&mysentsize=&mydocsize=&dpp=&spp=&spd=&text=lexform&mode=main&sort=gr_tagging&lang=ru&nodia=1&req=%E2%20%EF%F0%EE%F2%E8%E2%ED%EE%F1%F2%FC&p=0)). Процитирую одно из попавшихся:

> Д**о**лжно заметить, что Авенир, в противность всем чахоточным, нисколько не обманывал себя насчет своей болезни… и что ж?

Меня интересует, сейчас оно совсем устарело или нет и если да, то какие есть сейчас близкие аналоги. Что самому приходит в голову похожего, это *"в отличие от".* Или старое (**если только** оно действительно устарело) *"в противность"* заменилось таким же по смыслу, но более длинным *"в противоположность"?*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/ogegova/192178  Словарь говорит, что устаревшее:

ПРОТИ́ВНОСТЬ: в противность кому (чему), предл. с дат. (устар.) то же, что в отличие от кого-чего-н. В противность вам я оптимист.

А совсем или нет - как видите,  используется в художественных текстах прошлого и новых исторических произведениях с целью создания стилистики старого времени, для речевой характеристики. Слово книжное, в разговорной речи почти не используется, если только в речи старых интеллигентов.

Синонимы: в противовес, в противоположность.

Comment: Спасибо, Людмила!